# Array data not saving to specified sections. How to make seting independantly?

Tags: php, customization

I think I am writing the array part wrong. When saving on this array if you set all five settings, the setting from the 5th option is saved on all the settings. But if you then set the first four settings the setting on 4th is saved on all 5 settings.

This is the start of the function line:

Can this be improved where I write `$input`?

```
function thefunction($input) {
```

This is how I have the array part written:

```
$thisisit = array(
 'setting_one' => $input['setting_one'],
 'setting_two' => $input['setting_two'],
 'setting_three' => $input['setting_three'],
 'setting_four' => $input['setting_four'],
 'setting_five' => $input['setting_five']);
```

What can I add to make the settings set independently?

And saved with this for first add_option:

```
return sanitize_text_field(add_option($option_name, $thisisit, $deprecated, $autoload));
```

I have a option_update line also but it seems the add_option and option_update function fine. It must be the array definition part that is not good, right?

Here is the option_update line:

```
return sanitize_text_field(update_option($option_name, $thisisit));
```

I think I am writing the array part wrong.

Comment: [`add_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) and [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) return a boolean value, and so `wp_filter_nohtml_kses( {add|update}_option( ... ) )` will return `'1'` or `''` (ie, `true` or `false` cast to a `string`). Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/404955/edit) to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is `myarrayfun` meant to do? And why are you calling `wp_filter_nohtml_kses`? I can also see variables being used that don't exist, such as `$new_value` and `$deprecated`. You should also read what Pat said

Comment: Hey I made some edits yesterday. Any new comments for me?